# pass an object from controller to another controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

after Signup, how to be automatically redirected to the authentificate page and put the login and the password in the form of authenficate.html ?

the signupCtrl

```
demoApp.controller('signupCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location,User) {

    User=$scope.user;
    $scope.verification = function(isValid,User) {

        User=$scope.user;

        if (isValid) {
            $scope.message = "Submitted ";
            console.log(User);
            console.log(User.type);
            if(User.type=="recruteur")
            {
                window.alert("bonjour recruteur "+ User.email);
                $location.path("/auth");

            }
            else {

                window.alert("bonjour condidat "+ User.email);
                $location.path("/auth");
            }

        } else {
            $scope.message = "There are still invalid fields below";

        }
    };
});
```

the SINGUP.html

```
<body ng-controller="signupCtrl">
    <form name="registrationForm" novalidate
          ng-submit="submit(registrationForm.$valid)">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-group"
                   ng-model="user.email"
                   required />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"
                   ng-model="user.password"
                   required/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit"               ng-click="verification(registrationForm.$valid,registrationForm.user)">Register!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

controller authentificate:

```
demoApp.controller('personCtrl',function ($scope, $http,$location,User) {
    console.log(User);
     var person=User;
    $scope.emaill=person.email;
    $scope.pwd=person.password;
   console.log(person);
});
```

authentificate page:

```
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="emaill">
    <input type="password" ng-model="pwd">
    <input type="submit" value="Connexion" ng-click="connexion(person)">

</form>
</body>
```

the route provider

```
demoApp.config(['$routeProvider',

    function($routeProvider){
        //systeme de routage
        console.log('rederction');
        $routeProvider.when ('/auth',{templateUrl: 'authentficate.html',
            controller: 'personCtrl'})

            .otherwise({redirectTo: 'Signup.html'}
        );
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data that is needed for the session in a Service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

But dont put the Password there, only the Username and an Authentication token.

Check here for a complete sample for an token based authentication

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec